# Snap LineStrings considering direction in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, line, snapping

I have 2 projected shape files: Roads (red) and public transit routes (blue):
[image: Shapes]

I want to snap the PT routes to the roads, but because of inaccurate marks sometimes the routes are snapped to the wrong road segment. 
I wish to minimize the errors by considering the direction while snapping, and not only distance. Is there any way to do that in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using "*Snap Vertices To Nearest Points By Condition*" processing tool from [ProcessX Plug-In](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/):

- Convert your street lines to points. Either via "*Extract Vertices*" or "*Points Along Geometry*", both native processing tools. Which one you want to use is up to you, depending on your desired result. You may also need to do step 2 before this step depending on your method. Optionally you can also densify your transport lines at first.
- Calculate the angle in degrees for the points. "*Points Along Geometry*" will automatically add a field called `"angle"` in degrees to the result.
- Run "*Snap Vertices To Nearest Points By Condition*" and set it up the following:
- As `source layer` choose your `transport lines`
- As `points layer` choose your `just created points` from the street lines
- As `snap vertices` choose `all options`
- As `compare-expression for the source layer` choose `main_angle($geometry)`
- As `first cmparison operator` choose `>=` or `>`
- As `compare-expression for the points-layer` choose the angle field and substract a tolerance, for example `"angle" - 50`
- Choose `AND` as `concatenation operator`
- As `second compare expression` choose `main_angle($geometry)` again
- As `second comparison operator` choose `<=` or `<`
- As `second compare expression for the points-layer` choose the angle field and add a tolerance, for example `"angle" + 50`
- You can also set a `maximum snapping distance` if you like

[image]

Example result:

[image]

*Disclaimer: I am the author of ProcessX Plug-In.*

Answer (score 0):

From the Snapping toolbar in *QGIS*, using the trace tool can help in following the path direction. To access the snapping tool:

Right click on the menu bar> Select Snapping Toolbar.